# Unable to Launch in Eclipse

Tags: java

I have two class files & I've not been able to launch in eclipse. The first one:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class bear{
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner Bugs = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name");
    pee obj1 = new pee();
    String Name = Bugs.nextLine();
    obj1.PrintMessage(Name);
    Bugs.close();
}  }
```

And the second one:

```
public class pee {

   public void PrintMessage(String Name){
       System.out.println("Hello, your name is:" + Name);
   }
}
```

Comment: For starters, Java convention is to capitalize class names and start method and variable names with lowercase. Not following that makes your code difficult to read.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Please post any exception stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main class always should be public

```
public class bear{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner Bugs = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter your name");
     pee obj1 = new pee();
     String Name = Bugs.nextLine();
     obj1.PrintMessage(Name);
     Bugs.close();
   } 
}
```

Comment: No. In eclipse it isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Java naming conventions for Class and varibales like this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bear{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner bugs = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        Pee obj1 = new Pee();
        String name = bugs.nextLine();
        obj1.PrintMessage(name);
        bugs.close();
    }
}
```

And second class :

```
class Pee {
    public void printMessage(String name){
        System.out.println("Hello, your name is:" + name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare public on class bear if your java file is bear.java.
Here is the sample code:
bear.java

```
public class bear {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Bugs = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your name");
    pee obj1 = new pee();
    String Name = Bugs.nextLine();
    obj1.PrintMessage(Name);
    Bugs.close();
}
}

class pee {
public void PrintMessage(String Name) {
    System.out.println("Hello, your name is:" + Name);
}
}
```